# How to embed QWebView (QtJambi) on Java Swing Application?

Tags: java, swing, qtwebkit, qt-jambi

Is it possible to use QWebView to render HTML5 pages inside a Java Swing Application across Windows, Mac and Linux?

Basically I would like to have something like http://qupzilla.com but for Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think using QWebView in Swing is going to be easy.

If you just want to render HTML 5 in a Java Swing application its probably easier to use JavaFX's WebView (based on WebKit). You can use JFXPanel to add JavaFX's WebView to your Swing Application.

There is also MozSwing (Firefox bindings for Java).

If you just need XHTML + CSS3 you can take a look at flying-saucer which is a pure Java implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Do not hesitate to add references to projects home page or class documentation.

Comment: Just to comment that a project qtjambi-awtbridge exists to allow AwtInQt and QtInAwt it is not bug free and this is mainly due to lack of people filling bugs/testcases to look at.  This project currently exists up on gitorious.org and my personal clone provides some recent updates to it.